# Browser-sync not working in command line version

Tags: node.js, command-line, gulp, browser-sync

I have installed browser-sync in 2 ways:
1. globaly (npm install -g browser-sync)
2. localy with gulp (npm install gulp browser-sync)
Both are the same version: 2.11

When I use browser-sync with gulp, everything works fine.

When I try browser-sync in the command line, without gulp, it loads the page in the browser but it does not reload the page (index.html) when I make a change.

These are the messages I receive from browser-sync.

```
[BS] Serving files from: public
[BS] Watching files...
[BS] File changed: resources/assets/sass/styles.scss
[BS] File changed: resources/assets/sass/styles.scss
[BS] File changed: resources/assets/sass/styles.scss
```

It detects the file changes but does not reload the page.
Same version of browser-sync in gulp works perfectly.